# PuLP "symbol in wrong position" error and fix

Tags: python, pulp

PuLP sometimes gives errors when solving a linear optimization problem. For example, for the following code...

```
import pulp

model = pulp.LpProblem(sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
Q = pulp.LpVariable(name='Q', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
B = pulp.LpVariable(name='B', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
L = pulp.LpVariable(name='L', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

model += (4*Q + 4*B + 8*L <= 800, 'Milk')
model += (8*Q + 6*B + 4*L <= 1800, 'Sauce')
model += (8*Q + 4*B       <= 500, 'Powder')
model += 2*Q + 4*B + L

status = model.solve()
print('\n\n')
for x in model.variables():
    print(f'{x.name} = {x.value()}')
print(f'Profit = {model.objective.value()}')
```

... the following is printed in the cmd prompt:

> GLPSOL--GLPK LP/MIP Solver 5.0
> Parameter(s) specified in the command line:
> --cpxlp C:\Users\hadiz\AppData\Local\Temp\0f4d3803095c416890dc6125a83f96e8-pulp.lp
> -o C:\Users\hadiz\AppData\Local\Temp\0f4d3803095c416890dc6125a83f96e8-pulp.sol
> Reading problem data from 'C:\Users\hadiz\AppData\Local\Temp\0f4d3803095c416890dc6125a83f96e8-pulp.lp'...
> C:\Users\hadiz\AppData\Local\Temp\0f4d3803095c416890dc6125a83f96e8-pulp.lp:13: symbol 'B' in wrong position
> CPLEX LP file processing error
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "1a.py", line 13, in 
> status = model.solve()
> File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\Anaconda3-2019.10\install\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py", line 1913, in solve
> status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
> File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\Anaconda3-2019.10\install\lib\site-packages\pulp\apis\glpk_api.py", line 115, in actualSolve
> raise PulpSolverError("PuLP: Error while executing " + self.path)
> pulp.apis.core.PulpSolverError: PuLP: Error while executing glpsol.exe

Sometimes, for other codes similar to the above, instead of "symbol 'B' in wrong position", I get "symbol ':' in wrong position".

I'm using Anaconda3-2019.10. Python version: 3.7.4. PuLP version: 2.6.0.

I figured out a solution myself, so I thought I better write it here for future programmers. Your solutions are also very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

PuLP seems to have issues with strings starting with 'B' or 'b'; that is, variable and constraint names. So, if in the following code, we write

`B = pulp.LpVariable(name='_B', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')`

the problem magically gets solved.

Comment: There is something else going on here.  Your orig code runs/solves just fine for me using python 3.9 and CBC solver versions 2.9 and 2.10.  Is what you have above part of a large code that may have some name collisions or are you running it in a notebook or such where similar things can occur?

Comment: @AirSquid That's the whole code actually. So, it shouldn't be a name collision. I'll edit the question and include my python version.

Comment: @AirSquid for some reason pulp is trying to solve with GLPK before CBC in this case, which is weird. The variable name is an issue with GLPK particularly. I though this was "fixed" with a name check in PuLP, but apparently there are other forbidden names we are not checking.